# Count occurences of a row based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I below dataset of 10 million records with over 47 columns

| name | account | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 12345 | 100$ |
| user2 | 123456 | 200$ |
| user1 | 54321 | 200$ |
| user2 | 123456 | 100$ |

Couple of things I need to see here:

1. Sum of amounts for each of users and/or each account. This I believe I have achieved with below and it seems okay

```py
df.groupby(['account','name'])['amount'].sum()
```

2. Most active clients and accounts. So I need this data in one dataframe but I am failing to achieve this, I can only specify one of them

```py
df['account'].value_counts().to_frame().reset_index()
```

And that shows me how many times specific account shows up in the dataset.

| account | occurence |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | 2 |
| 54321 | 1 |
| 12345 | 1 |

What I need to see is the name of the client for each of these accounts.
I have tried below but it doesn't work.

```py
df[['account','name']].apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
```

Equals to

|  | account | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | NaN | 2.0 |
| user2 | NaN | 1.0 |

My desired result would be below:

| name | account | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 12345 | 100$ |
|  | 54321 | 200$ |
| user2 | 123456 | 300$ |

I have also tried creating a separate dataframe which would hold all unique accounts vs names and then merging it with the result of value_counts, but it's not showing the proper count of occurence.

Comment: What you can do is create an additional column named name_account containing the name and account joined together. Then use  `df.groupby('account_name')['amount'].sum()` to sum the duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first store the index of `value_counts` in a variable (`i`) , then assign the account column as **[`categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html)** with `ordered=True` (*This will retain the sorting order of `value_counts`*), then groupby and sum with `observed=True`:

```
i = df['account'].value_counts().index
acc = pd.Categorical(df['account'],i,ordered=True)
out = (df.assign(account=acc)
       .groupby(['name','account'],observed=True)['amount'].sum().to_frame())
```

---

```
print(out)

               amount
name  account        
user1 54321       200
      12345       100
user2 123456      300
```